# How to remove "href" with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, href

```
<a id="a$id" onclick="check($id,1)" href="javascript:void(0)"  class="black">Qualify</a>
```

After "href" is removed, is "Qualify" still clickable?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Your title question and your example are completely different.  I'll start by answering the title question:

```
$("a").removeAttr("href");
```

And as far as not requiring an href, the generally accepted way of doing this is:

```
<a href"#" onclick="doWork(); return false;">link</a>
```

The return false is necessary so that the href doesn't actually go anywhere.

Answer (score 29):

If you want your anchor to still appear to be clickable:

```
$("a").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer");
```

And if you wanted to remove the href from only anchors with certain attributes (eg ones that just have a hash mark as the href - this can be useful in asp.net)

```
$("a[href='#']").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer");
```

Comment: Also useful in Javascript, I added pointer-events: none as well.

$("a[href='#']").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer").css("pointer-events","none");

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted to remove the href, change the cursor and also prevent clicking on it, this should work:

`$("a").attr('href', '').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'pointer-events' : 'none'});`

Comment: This will add a second, blank href. So, if you have <a href="somewhere" />, you will now have <a href="somewhere" href="" />

Comment: . USE $("a").removeAttr("href");

Answer (score 9):

If you [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr) the `href` attribute the anchor will be not focusable and it will look like simple text, but it will still be clickable.

Comment: It is ok as long as it looks like plain text, not like a hyperlink or button.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('a').filter('[href^="http://"],[href^="https://"]').contents().unwrap();
```

or

```
$('a').filter('[href^="http://"],[href^="https://"]').removeAttr("href").css("cursor","not-allowed");
```