# Disable HREF by onclick inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, href

How can I disable the a `href` if an element with an `onclick` function is fired within the `<a>` element?

I tried `event.preventDefault();`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
How can I solve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".inside > .fa").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("TEST");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='/'>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='inside'>
      <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Take a look at `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: The click still bubbles upwards. Use `event.stopPropagation();` instead. You are using `event.preventDefault()` on an element that has no default click behaviour, so it does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "href" with Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688084/how-to-remove-href-with-jquery)

Comment: Your code above seems to work. (Although I can't explain why `preventDefault` does what `stopPropagation` seems like it should.) Are you including the jQuery library? Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click still bubbles upwards. Use `event.stopPropagation();` instead. You are using `event.preventDefault()` on an element that has no default click behaviour, so it does nothing.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".inside > .fa").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target);
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block; /* required otherwise you cannot have block level elements like div inside a */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='https://google.com' target="_top">
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='inside'>
      <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Weirdly, `stopPropagation` doesn't seem to stop the link from being followed. I get "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame... The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set."

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I see that in both Firefox and Chrome, although Firefox doesn't throw the same message. But in both browsers, if I remove the `target="_top"` and/or change the `href` to a relative path, the link still executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault()` to stop event bubling

Comment: Please note that your selector `.inside > .fa` will only disable href when clicking on the inside `.fa` element. Change the selector to `.inside, .inside > .fa` to disable event bubbling when clicking on the `.inside` div as well.

Comment: Another thing to consider: move `return false` to the very end of the function if you want your `alert` statement to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Register your event listener on the `<a>` tag. And the make the changes below. This takes advantage of *Event Delegation* (a good thing).

you'll need both of these:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

**Add**

event.stopPropagation();

And then finally, you'll need to test to make sure the element clicked *was not* the `<a>`;  So your code will look like this:

Here is a codepen that demonstrates this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyJgWB?editors=1111

Comment: right my mistake...the event listener must be registered on the anchor tag.

Comment: @Dennis - take a look at the answer now please